# Is there a better way to block incoming/outgoing connections than the hosts file (Mac)

Tags: macos

Editing `/etc/hosts` works to easily block/unblock sites, but if you already have a browser open, it doesn't work until the browser cache is flushed.

Is there any simple way on OSX to block connections to certain hosts, preferably without 3rd party software? I imagine Little Snitch does what I need behind the scenes, if anyone understands how that works.

Comment: you specify *without 3rd party software*, but it would be criminal not to mention that [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) does what you want brilliantly! And should be a standard install on every OSX machine connected to the internet!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Love little snitch! I'm looking to develop a piece of software that can block sites on it's own, similar functionality, any idea how LS works under the hood?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 ways to do this on Mac OS X without requiring you to do a lot more.

1. You have already mentioned the first way - using `/etc/hosts`.
2. You have also ruled out using the second way - using browser plugins.
3. The 3rd way is to use the "Parental Controls" feature under System Preferences.

There is a 4th way - if you are talking about writing code and implementing your own script or your own custom app.

If you are talking about "under the hood" level implementation - i.e. you want to implement a custom application of your own (similar to Little Snitch), then you should get yourself familiar with the concept of `iptables` (linux systems routinely use this to control access rights to specific hosts and ports).

In Mac OS (which essentially is FreeBSD under the hood), the equivalent is `ipfw` (IP Firewall) and for Mac OS 10.7 onwards, `ipfw` has been deprecated in favour of `pf` (Packet Filter).

Reference article which you can refer to: http://ikawnoclast.com/security/mac-os-x-pf-firewall-avoiding-known-bad-guys/

Comment: Thanks for adding to your answer, that's what I was looking for.